# Keep the same pathname in Link, only add query params in Next.JS

Tags: next.js13

i want to redirect the user to same path, but add an query parameter, using Next Links. How i can do that? Actually the preview is ok, but when clicked the user will be redirect to Home "/". PS: I'm using Next.JS 13, and i want this to be server side redering soon i can't use useRouter().

https://i.ibb.co/Xxf3G4p/Untitled.png
https://i.ibb.co/7Xygvxw/image.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[update]

To get the current path in the server side to not use a client component, you can do it from your page component using getServerSideProps.

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async 
(context) => {
    const path = context.resolvedUrl;

   return {
      props: {
         path,
     },
   };
};
```

Now you can grab the path from the props and use it in your page component directly or pass it to a child;

```
export default function Page({ path }: { path: string }) {
  //avoid issues with the query string
  const pathname = path.split("?")[0];
  return (
    <Link
      href={{
      pathname,
      query: { lang: "en" },
     }}
    >
    Your Link
   </Link>
  );
}
```

You're link is missing the path, you're just defining the query parameter. If you want to keep the same route and just append the query string, you can do it as follow:

Get the current path with useRouter

```
const { pathname } = useRouter();
```

Add the query string to the same path on link click;

```
<Link
  href={{
    pathname: pathname,
    query: { lang: "en" },
  }}
>
  Your Link
</Link>
```

Comment: In Next.JS 13, i can't use useRouter() because i want the Link be render in server side. https://i.ibb.co/ZYVPy9c/image.png PS:I accidentally put the pathname in the wrong place but that doesn't change the problem

Comment: This example uses the useRouter hook just to get the current pathname, the next/link component will trigger the server side render.

Comment: Ok, but why i receive this error? https://i.ibb.co/ZYVPy9c/image.png

Comment: This because in next/13 all components are server components by default. If you want to interact with the navigation which is client side, you have to write "use client" on the top of your tsx file.

Comment: Note that this does not mean that your page will not be server side rendered.

Comment: Thanks. The only option is using client side to get the pathname right? Now with 'use client' i receive this error "Error: NextRouter was not mounted. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted"

Comment: I'm not sure what could be the cause of the error, can you provide a screenshot?. Also let me update the question with the server side option to get the path.